# OpenCV Android NDK: non-system libraries in linker error

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

This is the error I get, I followed different guides to install and run NDK but just couldn't manage it. Always a problem

```
20:58:58 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****
"C:\\Users\\Gok2\\workspace\\android-ndk-r9b\\ndk-build.cmd" 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:detection_based_tracker: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using     LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so
```

Comment: Are you able to run yor project ? I am facing the same problem. the sample buils fine but whenver i try to run it in a device it force closes. if you have solved then guide me . .thanks in advance

Comment: Please look at this : http://answers.opencv.org/question/22060/warningjniandroidmkdetection_based_tracker-non/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error. This warning has been introduced recently, in the latest release of NDK. The OpenCV build scripts have not yet accomodated the necessary workarounds, but I have no doubt the fix will be ready quite soon.

In the mean time, you can ignore the warning. I would advise to keep your eye on it, so that except for opencv libraries, no unexpected names appear in the build log.